# como editar select option con php jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estimados señores me gustaría me ayuden estamos en un proyecto de registro de visitas y tenemos un problema.
Que la momento de editar datos del visitante en el combobox departamentos, provincias y distritos debe de jalar el departamento, provincia y distrito de ese visitante, debajo de esa información debe aparecer el combobox con el resto de información para seleccionar y ser editado. Dejo el ejemplo de de departamentos

```
<div class="col form-group">
              <label for="depVisitanteEdiatar">Seleccione un departamento</label>
                <select class="custom-select" id="depVisitanteEdiatar" name="depVisitanteEdiatar">
                <option value="0">Departamento</option>
                <?php
                $sqldepas = "SELECT * FROM departamentos";
                $consultadepas = $conexion->query($sqldepas);
                while ($valoresDepas = mysqli_fetch_array($consultadepas)) {
                  echo "<option value='" .
                    $valoresDepas['id'] .
                    "'>" .
                    $valoresDepas['departamentos'] .
                    "</option>";
                }
                ?>
              </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: Buenas noches, ¿podrías ejemplificar lo que necesitas? _Debajo de esa información debe aparecer el combobox con el resto de información para seleccionar y ser editado_ Como con un boceto o algo que ya más o menos tengas hecho con lo que esperas tener al final gráficamente.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que con un foreach quedaría todo más limpio y no deberías tener problemas a la hora de mostrar el combobox te dejo el código que yo he hecho para tu caso:

```html
<div class="col form-group">
    <label for="depVisitanteEdiatar">Seleccione un departamento</label>
    <select class="custom-select" id="depVisitanteEdiatar" name="depVisitanteEdiatar">
        <option value="0">Departamento</option>
        <?php
            foreach (mysqli_query ( $conexion, "SELECT * FROM departamentos") as $elementos_departamentos => $valoresDepas) {
                echo "<option value='" . 
                $valoresDepas['id'] . 
                "'>" . 
                $valoresDepas['departamentos'] . 
                "</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Si hubiese cualquier error agradecería que me comentáseis, ya que no lo puedo ejecutar en este momento.